# parse.com wherekey doesnotmatchkey in query doesnot filter the objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

> I have Parse classes  Doctor->name,clinic,address... Patients->
>   name,phone... Appointments-> Doctor,patient,Date

I am trying to run sub query to return the records of doctors who do not have any bookings for particular date

```
    let queryDoctor = PFQuery(className: Doctor.parseClassName())
    let queryAppointment = PFQuery(className:Bookings.parseClassName())
    queryDoctor.whereKey("objectId", doesNotMatchKey:"Doctor.objectId", inQuery: queryAppointment)
    queryDoctor.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock 
    {
        (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print(results)
    }
```

but the query seem to return all the records of doctors without considering the `wherekey` method of `PFQuery`.
Any suggestoins??

Comment: From what I can tell in my experimentation, whereKey:doesNotMatchKey is a no-op. Has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
queryDoctor.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(etc...
```

hope this helps